# Repeating same block of code over an ActiveRecord Object's attributes in Ruby (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a basic function which takes in different values for weight and reps for a barbell lift, and converts it to an estimated one rep max, which gets stored in my database. Here is what the code currently looks like:

```
  if deadlift_reps != 1
    self.deadlift = deadlift_wt * deadlift_reps * 0.0333 + deadlift_wt
  else
    self.deadlift = deadlift_wt
  end

  if squat_reps != 1
    self.squat = squat_wt * squat_reps * 0.0333 + squat_wt
  else
    self.squat = squat_wt
  end

  if benchpress_reps != 1
    self.benchpress = benchpress_wt * benchpress_reps * 0.0333 + benchpress_wt
  else
    self.benchpress = benchpress_wt
  end

  if overheadpress_reps != 1
    self.overheadpress = overheadpress_wt * overheadpress_reps * 0.0333 + overheadpress_wt
  else
    self.overheadpress = overheadpress_wt
  end
```

I am obviously repeating myself a lot in this code block, but cannot figure out how to break it out and interpolate the method names. I've tried using an array with

```
  lifts = [deadlift, squat, benchpress, overheadpress]
```

But when I try using each do on this to string interpolate, I am getting an error that lifts doesn't have this method.

Can anyone offer me any advice on how to proceed?

edit:

The loop I was trying to do was:

```
lifts = [deadlift, squat, benchpress, overheadpress]

lifts each do |lift|
  if '#{lift}_reps' !=1
    self.#{lift} = '#{lift}_wt' * '#{lift}_reps' * 0.0333 + '#{lift}'_wt
  else
    self.#{lift} = '#{lift}_wt'
  end
end
```

I can see why this isn't working, but, using a similar idea, how would I make it work?

Comment: can you share the caller of this method?  what is the method name btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a private method to calculate every piece of:

```
if deadlift_reps != 1
   ...
end
```

and assign the values to different fields (deadlift, squat, benchpress, overheadpress) using the **assign_attributes** Active record methods.

Here is the code, I didn't test it, but it should work:

```
  [["deadlift", 20, 8], 
   ["squat", 10, 12],
   ["benchpress", 30, 6],
   ["overheadpress", 20, 10]]).each do |exercize, wt, reps|
    set_exercize(exercize, wt, reps)
  end

  private

  def set_exercize(exercize, wt, reps)
    value = reps != 1 ? wt * reps * 0.0333 + wt : wt
    self.assign_attributes(exercize => value)
  end
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Small issue: `set_exercize` signature has three args, you're calling it with one.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to get this to work.